# How do I get vb.net to add all links within a particular div class from a webpage

Tags: html, vb.net, facebook, html-agility-pack

I want to add in the list box items:

```
https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX

https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX
```

document:

```
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab"
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab"
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab"
```

Comment: well, what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

```
Dim html = File.ReadAllText("Path")
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)

Dim anchorTexts As New List(Of String)
Dim divNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fsl fwb fcb']")
If Not divNodes Is Nothing Then
    For Each div In divNodes
        For Each anchorNode In div.SelectNodes("//a")
            Dim href As String = anchorNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(href) Then
                anchorTexts.Add(href)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Dim html = File.ReadAllText("Path") file not found. i want to listbox1.items.add(href)?

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen: of course it is not found. Sorry, but if you are already familiar with `HtmlAgilityPack` that suggests that you are more experienced. I have used it because i needed a way to get your sample string as text. The easiest way is to use a file. So just replace `Dim html = File.ReadAllText("Path")` with your string. According to the question how you get the list intro a `ListBox`: either use a loop and add the items or use it as datasource.

Comment: ı can not . are you code?